# Rails 3: ActiveRecord results and Array#include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is my model structure:

```
A User has and belongs to many groups
A Group has many subscriptions
A Group has and belongs to many users
A Group has many GroupAdmins
A Subscription belongs to a group
A GroupAdmin belongs to a user
A GroupAdmin belongs to a Group
```

When I query the DB (using active record), I should be able to do something like this:

```
u = User.find 47238
```

In my User model I have a method called subscriptions:

```
def subscriptions
    self.groups.where(:status => 'active').collect { |group| group.subscriptions.where("subscriptions.status = ? AND subscriptions.expiration_date > ?", 'active', "#{Time.zone.now}").last  }.flatten
  end
```

and then to continue with my query:

```
u.subscriptions.first.group.group_admins
```

The above returns me a record of a group and the user id I initally queried on.. but for some reason when I run this method inside of Group I get a false returned:

```
def is_group_admin?(user)
    self.group_admins.include? user
  end
```

Working Code:

```
def is_admin?(user)
    self.group_admins.collect { |ga| ga.user }.include? user
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_admins` returns a collection of GroupAdmin objects. These may correspond  (via their user_id) to a user but they aren't actually users so `group_admins.include?(user)` can only return false.

Depending on what you are doing you could call `include?` on `group_admins.collect {|ga| ga.user}` or search for a GroupAdmin with the appropriate `user_id` value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I will put the working code above